# Modify XML file and save | Java | Android

Tags: java, android, xml

it's my first question here so forgive me any mistakes.

I want to modify a specific value through my code in an XML file that's built like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- STATION settings -->
        <!-- Example: <add key="settingName" value="settingValue"/> -->
        <add key="station_id" value="0001"/>
        <add key="debugging" value="FALSE"/>
        <add key="lang" value="1"/>
        <add key="lokales_lesen_schreiben" value="FALSE"/>
        <add key="data_path" value="/pdac/"/>
        <add key="data_dbconn" value="\my documents\pdaControl\pdac_local.sdf"/>
        <add key="layout" value="actlayout_1"/>
        <add key="connection_timeout" value="10"/>
        <add key="soundfile_good" value="[APP]\Media\iwrgood.wav"/>
        <add key="soundfile_bad" value="[APP]\Media\iwrbad.wav"/>
        <add key="soundfile_quest" value="[APP]\Media\iwrask.wav"/>
        <!--<add key="device_assembly" value="[APP]\iw_Symbol.dll"/>
        <add key="device_class" value="iw_Symbol.clsSymbol"/>-->
        <add key="device_execute"
             value="ENABLE_DEFAULTCODES;SET_2OF5_RANGE(0,0),ENABLE_REDUNDANCY(3OF9,2OF5);ENABLE_VERIFY(3OF9,2OF5);ENABLE_CHECKTRANS(3OF9,2OF5)"/>
        <add key="device_action_good" value="LED_GREEN;VIBRATION_SHORT"/>
        <add key="device_action_bad" value="BEEP_MID(1);LED_RED;VIBRATION_LONG"/>
        <add key="device_action_quest" value="BEEP_MID(1);LED_RED;VIBRATION_MID"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here I want to edit the "value" entry.

At the moment I try to solve my Problem with this Code but the XML doesnt change

```
 try
    {
        String filepath = path;
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File(path));

        Node configuration = document.getFirstChild();

        Node add = document.getElementsByTagName("add").item(0);

        //update

        NodeList list = configuration.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++){

            Node attr = list.item(i);

            if (vordererWert.contains(attr.getNodeName())){
                attr.setTextContent(Eingabe);
            }

        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce)
    {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sae)
    {
        sae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce)
    {
        tce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException te)
    {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

I hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Explain more otherwise someone can answer like you can edit manually

Comment: I' ve added some informations